# Derivative of a matrix given with a root

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let us defined the operator $\boldsymbol{N}(x)=\sqrt{\boldsymbol{M}^{\dagger-1}(x)\,\boldsymbol{M}^{-1}(x)}$.

assuming that we know $\frac{d\boldsymbol{M}(x)}{dx}$, how do I compute $\frac{d\boldsymbol{N}(x)}{dx}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac {dN}{dx}$? What is $x$? Is $N$ a function of $x$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: I corrected the question according to your comment.

Comment: Define
$\,W=M^{-1}\:$
then implicitly differentiate
$\,N^2=W^\dagger W\;$ utilizing
$\;\dot W=-W\,\dot M\,W\;$ You'll end up with a [Sylvester equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) for the unknown derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As greg hint indicates, we can proceed with a kind of implicit differentiation. Let $M'$ denote the derivative $M' = dM/dx$. Note that
$$
M^\dagger N^2M = I.
$$
Differentiating on both sides yields
$$
[M']^\dagger N^2 M + M^\dagger N^2 M' + M^\dagger(NN' + N'N)M = 0
$$
Rearranging the equation gives us
$$ 
M^\dagger(NN' + N'N)M = -[M']^\dagger N^2 M - M^\dagger N^2 M' \implies\\
NN' + N'N = -[M^{-1}]^\dagger[M']^\dagger N^2 - N^2 M'M^{-1},
$$
which is a [Sylvester equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) that can be solved for $N'$. The fact that $N$ is positive definite ensures that the solution to this equation is unique.

In fact, this is not just a Sylvester equation, it's more specifically a (continuous time) [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation). As such, its solution can be given explicitly as the result of a certain integral.

In particular, if we denote $$
Q = -[M^{-1}]^\dagger[M']^\dagger N^2 - N^2 M'M^{-1},
$$
then the equation for $N'$ above may be written in the form
$$
(-N)N' + N'(-N) + Q = 0,
$$
so that
$$
N'(x) = \int_{0}^\infty e^{-yN(x)}Qe^{-yN(x)}\,dy.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to note: I think that there is a little sign typo in your equation.

Comment: If the matrix $M$ is unbounded (for example, containing Dirac delta functions). Is this argument still valid?

Comment: @Yair As long as $M'$ is well-defined (in the sense of distributions, as is required for dealing with Dirac delta functions), this argument is still valid.

Comment: @Yair Also, see my latest edit regarding the integral formula

Comment: @Yair Also I finally caught the typos